# How to obtain selected account ID and property ID with Google Embed API

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to pull some data out of GA using the Google API for PHP, including the user's selected currency type.

I have working PHP code (in isolation), but in order to pull the user's selected currency data I need to pull the user's `Google_Service_Analytics_Profile` and I need 3 IDs in total to get the profile: `$accountId`, `$webPropertyId`, `$profileId`.

Here's my PHP code that pulls the data:

```
    // Create a connection to the GA API service
    $analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);

    // Select the GA profile using the provided IDs
    $ga_profile = $analytics->management_profiles->get($input_data->account_id, $input_data->property_id, $input_data->profile_id);
```

As can be seen [from the source](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Service/Analytics.php#L3116), the `Google_Service_Analytics_ManagementProfiles_Resource::get()` method requires the three IDs mentioned above.

I want to use the Embed API to show the user a selector to allow them to choose the profile that I show data for and I intend to POST the selected IDs to my PHP code which pulls the data from GA and processes it.

Unfortunately, it seems that the only ID that the Embed API returns is the "View ID", which I understand is the `$profileID` above, but I'm lost as to how I find the remaining `$accountId` and `$webPropertyId` IDs to allow me to pull the "Analytics Profile" through the PHP API.

How do I get the remaining IDs?

Here's my HTML and JS: http://jsbin.com/naxiyomeko/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Try the account summary report  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accountSummaries  One request gives you everything the user has access to but you will have to scan though them to find the one your looking for.

Comment: I do not understand how you want to use the Embed API with PHP (the Embed API is by Googles definition a Javascript library, plus the view selector of the Embed API returns account- property and view IDs). Can you make your question a bit clearer in that respect ?

Comment: @EikePierstorff I've added a little more of an explanation on how I intend to transfer the IDs from the Embed (JavaScript) API to the PHP API on the server.

Comment: @DaImTo The issue with what you are suggesting is that I've no reliable way of knowing the IDs for the selected value in the Google Embed API `viewSelector`

Comment: @MasterRoot24 I think DalmTo suggests to use the Management API in PHP rather than try to mix technologies and try to get data from the JS Embed API to PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the remaining IDs from the Google Embed API `ViewSelector` using the following Javascript for the `change` event:

```
viewSelector.on('change', function() {
    ids = {}
    ids['account_id'] = viewSelector.B.fb;
    ids['property_id'] = viewSelector.HC.fb;
    ids['profile_id'] = viewSelector.RF.fb;
    // Do something with `ids` object here...
});
```

Updated JS bin: http://jsbin.com/hirapupayi/1/edit?html,js,console,output